# Get value from object

Tags: javascript

I am passing a string to a function, which will use this string to create a session storage element like this :

```
fun("key","value");

function fun(string, data){
  var to_session = {string:data};
  sessionStorage.setItem(string, JSON.stringify(to_session));
}
```

But in session storage instead of storing it as `{"key":"value"}` its stored as `{"string":"value"}`

Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: have you tried using a different variable name than 'string'? because I believe it is also a type definer.

Comment: it is, but the problem is that it is being literally interpreted rather than getting the value - anything you pass in will be set as the key.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
function fun(string, data){
  var to_session = {};
  to_session[string] = data;
  sessionStorage.setItem(string, JSON.stringify(to_session));
}
```